# Acces symfony web server on Vagrant machine from host with localhost

Tags: php, symfony, http, vagrant, port

I created a Vagrant machine with an ubuntu 14.04 (vagrant file below).

I forwarded host port 8080 to guest port 8000.

I have a symfony project on host (Vagrant file folder) (just a symfony new myproject built).

I ssh to guest machine and execute php app/console server:run (web server is up) on /vagrant folder

I try to acces localhost:8080 from a host browser and I have no answer.

How can I access to symfony web server from host machine?

I simplified at max level my vagrant and provision files for easy readability.

This is my vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"      
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
end
```

provision.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
apt-get update > /dev/null
apt-get install --assume-yes php5-cli
```

when I do nmap localhost on guest machine:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-28 09:04 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
5432/tcp open  postgresql
8000/tcp open  http-alt
```

Thanks a lot!

Jordi

Comment: Have you tried `http://10.10.10.10:8080` (your private network ip and external port)?

Comment: `"I forwarded host port 8080 to guest port 8000."`, that pretty much answers your question. You should open `localhost:8000`, since you forwarded it to local port `8000` and not `8080`.

Comment: @qooplmao Yes, I tryed but were no answer :-(

Comment: @Oldskool I also tried forward 8000 to 8000 and It didn't work. If you make vagrant init, you have a vagrant file with a port forwading example, it says:

# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

It let me think when you browse from host to localhost:8080, http request is received on guest machine at 80 (or 8000 as I modify this example)

:-S

Comment: Is the server listening to the correct ip/port? Have you tried running the server using `php app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000`?

Comment: @qooplmao Yes, php app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000 works!

I thought guest machine receives request as localhost, not as another ip (now I think is received as host private ip)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @qooplmao for this answer.

I create an answer because maybe it will be easier to find for another with similar problem.

The problem is that symfony server launched with `app/console server:run` just heard from 127.0.0.1 requests.

To solve this, @qooplmao tell me we can launch symfony web server for all ip.

Just doing: `app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000`
Oh! If you want to stop it, you have to `app/console server:stop 0.0.0.0:8000`

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

in symfony3 you need to use this:

```
cd project directory
php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and stop server with pressing
    ctrl + c