# Access Symfony's localhost:8000 on other devices in the same network

Tags: php, symfony, networking

I am developing a symfony project on my local machine, I wish to test it on my mobile via IP (both machines connected to wifi network). how do I access port 8000 (symfony's default port) on my mobile phone?

I already know about accessing localhost via IP of the serving device, but I want to access the port too(8000) which I cannot fetch from my devices!

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered to [another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388034/acces-symfony-web-server-on-vagrant-machine-from-host-with-localhost) this might be solved when adding the parameter `0.0.0.0:8000` to let Symfony not only respond to local requests but also accept requests from other devices.

The call then should look something like this:

```
php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

Same way you accessing it from your local machine but using it's IP address e.g.:

```
http://192.168.1.2:8000
```

where 192.168.1.2 is your machine IP address in local network (check it using ipconfig command - on Windows or ifconfig on Linux/Mac OS X). Please make sure your firewalls (on local machine and on router) does not block this (8000) port.

UPD: By the way, as far as I remember, Symfony's default port is 8080, not 8000. Please check it carefully.

Comment: It's 8000 on my machine, but seems simply using the IP followed by the port is not working! I have my firewall turned off on my mac...